# Context menu jumps

Tags: sharepoint-online

When right clicking on documents in SharePoint Online to reveal the context menu, the menu jumps for some reason which results in clicking on the wrong options. For example, if you want to click Download, the jump causes you to accidently click on Delete as shown in the video in the link below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOrPt.jpg

Is it possible to stop this from happening?

Using fully updated Windows 10 and Edge.

Answer (score 0):

When you move the mouse, don't make it too fast.

If you feel unstable, left-click on the ellipsis, the same effect, don't move too fast.
[image]

========================================
[image]